# Change activity on multiple screens

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 20.10

My setup is the following:

- Laptop (set as primary screen, with the dock and the bar on the top)
- External monitor (no dock or bar)

On Ubuntu 20.04, if I'm not mistaken, when I changed activities (Ctrl+Alt+arrow_key_down) I moved to a new activity within both screens.

With Ubuntu 20.10, when I move to a new activity, only the main screen changes to that activity, the external monitor keeps whatever windows were open.

Is this the new normal behaviour? Can be changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to

- open Gnome-tweaks (You may need to `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`)
- Open the `Workspaces` Tab
- Select `Workspaces span display`

Is it the behaviour you wanted?
(sorry I don't have my second monitor here)